# Memory visibility guarantees provided by intrinsic locking in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, locking, volatile

I need some clarity on what memory visibility guarantees are provided by using an intrinsic lock in Java.

So for example say if I have a HashMap object that maps Strings to Person objects like so:

```
HashMap<String,Person> m = new HashMap<String, Person>();
```

And lets say we have a synchronized method inside the same class like so:

```
public synchronized void addToMap(String name, Person p){
   m.put(name, p);
}
```

And also the same class has another synchronized method called get, like so:

```
public synchronized Person get(String name){
   return m.get(name);
}
```

So I have two questions.

1

Now lets say Thread A acquires the lock and exectutes the addToMap method., then exits the method and releases the lock.

And then Thread B comes along ,outside the locked method, and changes the state of the Person object that the reference p refers to.

Then, when Thread C acquires the same lock that Thread A had and executes the get() method, is Thread C guaranteed to retrieve the Person object in its most recent state? i.e. after Thread B changed it.

Now this example is highly contrived and if I was using a map with multiple threads then I know I should use ConcurrentHashMap etc, this example is just used to better explain my confusion on visibility guarantees.

I know that when a Thread acquires a lock, it is guaranteed to see any changes that were made to the state of the object from the previous Thread who held that lock,
so am I correct in thinking that because Thread B's activity was performed without obtaining the lock, then it is not guaranteed that Thread C will see the changes?

2

Now if my assumption for Question 1 is correct, then lets say Thread B did actually change the state of the Person object that the reference p refers to inside a synchronized method ,
so it has acquired the lock, then is C guaranteed to see the change that B made?
My initial assumption here is that C is guaranteed to see the change that B made, but when I thought about, I am not sure if the actual change, to the Person object p refers to, actually
changes the state of the HashMap(which is part of the state of the locked object) as it is not a structural modification like adding or deleting a mapping.

I know that intrinsic locking provides visibility and atomicity guarantees, and volatile variables guarantee only visibility, but my confusion comes on how these guarantees relate to actual Objects(eg the actual Objects in a mapping
like the Person object p refers to), rather than just the object references.

Any help to clear this up would be great thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know that when a Thread acquires a lock, it is guaranteed to see any changes that were made to the state of the object from the previous Thread who held that lock, so am I correct in thinking that because Thread B's activity was performed without obtaining the lock, then it is not guaranteed that Thread C will see the changes?

Yes. Basically, it doesn't matter how you got hold of the object (in this case through a person-reference stored in a map).

Regardless what the thread changes, since it's not holding a lock, it's not part of a happens-before relation, thus subsequent reads are not guaranteed to see the update.

> Now if my assumption for Question 1 is correct, then lets say Thread B did actually change the state of the Person object that the reference p refers to inside a synchronized method , so it has acquired the lock, then is C guaranteed to see the change that B made?

If Thread B did hold a lock, and that lock was later acquired by Thread C, then Thread C would see the changes that Thread B made, regardless if the changes were inside a map and so on.

But, it's important to keep in mind that just because you're introducing locks doesn't mean that you don't have data races. Without further synchronization, there's no guarantee that Thread B actually acquires the lock before Thread C.

Hope I understood your question correctly and I hope my answer was clear. Please let me know otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

1) True.

2) True, assuming that Thread B:

- changed p holding the SAME lock, OR
- invoked addToMap method after modifications, and in that case it does not matter whether Thread B made changes inside or outside of a sync block.

However, there is another potential issue, and that is the visibility of the m HashMap itself:

```
m = new HashMap<String, Person>();
```

This code is not synchronized, meaning that m will be visible to only the thread that created the object which contains m. Other threads may see null or inconsistent state of the map. The solution is to declare m to be either volatile or final (that's why most immutable objects have to declare their fields to be final, it's not just a convention to do so).

The complete description of happens-before relationship can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5).

Answer (score 0):

afaict, in the example you provided the first lock is on the map only (i.e. it affects only the presence/absence of a given Person in that map), while the second one is on the Person instance. If some field of a Person gets changed while the Person is being added to the list, the implicit synchronizations shouldn't affect each other, so they won't change the behavior nor affect potential clients (accessors) of the Person instance in any way.

Comment: Are you suggesting that he should acquire the lock of the person instead?

Comment: well, if an accessor wants to check whether the Person is in the map, the lock should be acquired on the map. Instead, if the accessor wants to check the state of the Person, the lock should be acquired on the Person instance. What I'm trying to say is that the two locks serve different purposes and should not affect each other's behavior.

Comment: Hmm.. As long as both threads agree on the same lock, then I don't see how it matters which lock they use. Surely it can make sense from a logical point of view, but semantically I don't think it matters which object they lock on.

Comment: I guess my question is really how far from the lock does the memory visibility guarantee extend? Is it guaranteed that Thread C will see ALL the changes Thread B has made, or only the changes that affected the state of the object who's lock has been acquired? And I am not sure if the change to the Person object really affects the state of that locked object? Please let me know if that question makes sense, if not I will try word it differently. thanks :)

Comment: All changes are seen. (A common pattern is to use a dummy object for locking: `Object lock = new Object()`) This would be pretty meaningless if it didn't cover changes to "unrelated" variables.

Comment: OK great stuff thanks. And I take it that with a volatile reference( eg. private volatile Person p;  the memory visibility is only guaranteed on the reference itself, rather than the Person object p refers to?

Comment: OK, so then we cannot ever use volatile on actual objects? only on object references. if that is the case, then can we never guarantee object change visibility using volatile, only by using locking? which would be kind of counter intuitive seen as locking and volatile have the same memory visibility semantics. Still confused! lol

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77711/discussion-between-fulhamhead-and-aioobe).